# How to open a new window for each graph plot so they stay displayed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a program that works ok and plots graphs from the data file provided. The program opens a csv file, filters the data in column 5 for unique values and writes a csv file for each unique values accompanied with the data from the original file and I plot this to compare the different values in each column.
So for this example I should have 3 unique values in column 5, which creates 3 unique csv files with the prefix blue, green and red. I then plot say column 2 for each blue green red file and compare in the plot - so I will run through all the columns in the blue, green, red csv files and compare them in the plot.

I would like to keep the previous plot open when looking at the next plot, instead of having to close the plot window. I have tried using plt.figure() but was getting three charts open a the same time - apologies for bad programming I just started to learn Python.Thanks for any help/advice.

From line 40 onwards on the program is the plotting code I was having problems with

```
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
# import random used for changing line colors in chart
import random
from itertools import cycle

# opens a the input file and reads in the data
with open('Test_colours_in.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
# prints list of unique values in column 5 of csv of input file
    my_list = set()
    for line in csv_reader:
        my_list.add(line['Name5'])
    print(my_list)

# takes these unique values and creates files associated with each unique value
    for item in my_list:
        with open(item + '_'+'Test.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
            fieldnames = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8']
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            csv_writer.writeheader()

# filters the original file for each item in the list of unique values and writes them to respective file
            csv_file.seek(0)  # Reposition to front of file
            filtered = filter(lambda r: r['Name5'] == item, csv_reader)
            for row in filtered:
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
# Section of code below plots data from each of the filtered files
# reads in columns 1 for time (x) and 3,4 for y1 and y2

# to test for data type in column 0,1,2
# loops up to 3 (not including 3 )
#
# list of color for plots https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html
# color values choice below
# b , g, r, c, m, y, tab:blue, tab:orange, tab:purple, tab:gray
#
# this is the bit of code I am have trouble with I need to run through a list of columns and
# have previous plots visible when a look at the next graph. At the moment I have just picked the first
# three column and loop through these
    for i in range(3):
        # apples, pears and oranges really Name1,Name2 and Name3 will change these later
        user_input = input('enter Name1, Name2 or Name3, q to quit ?')
        sample_string = user_input
        if sample_string[:1] == 'q':
            break
        if sample_string == 'Name1':
            user = int(0)
        if sample_string == 'Name2':
            user = int(1)
        if sample_string == 'Name3':
            user = int(2)

        for item in my_list:
            print(user)

            # Chooses a random number between 1 and 16777215
            random_number = random.randint(1, 16777215)
            # convert the random number to a hex number then to string
            hex_number = str(hex(random_number))
            # [2;] removes the 0x from the hexadecimal and add #
            hex_number = '#' + hex_number[2:]
            print(random_number)
            x, y = np.loadtxt(item + '_'+'Test.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=[0, user], unpack=True, delimiter=',')
            plt.plot(x, y, hex_number, label=item, linewidth=5)

            style.use('ggplot')

        plt.title('Data v Time')
        plt.ylabel('Data')
        plt.xlabel('Time seconds')

        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True, color='k')
        plt.show()
```

## csv file below

Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8
1,2,3,4,Red,6,7,8
2,5,6,7,Blue,6,7,8
3,5,7,7,Blue,6,7,8
4,5,8,7,Blue,6,7,8
5,2,4,4,Red,6,7,8
6,2,5,4,Red,6,7,8
7,8,10,10,Green,6,7,8
8,8,11,10,Green,6,7,8
9,8,12,10,Green,6,7,8

Comment: Hi - thanks for that reply. I do get all the information in one graph as you say. But what I am trying to do is for each plot to remain on the screen as I move to the next selection so I can compare.

Comment: I updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: check out plt.ion() from the second answer

Answer (score 0):

To show all plots at once

move `plt.show()` outside from iteration (move it one level left) `for i in range(3):`

To stay in an interactive mode use `plt.ion()` (call it before the first plt use) more datails [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the plots one by one at each iteration, then you can do something like this:

```py
    for i in range(3):
        # ...

        plt.figure()

        plt.title('Data v Time')
        plt.ylabel('Data')
        plt.xlabel('Time seconds')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True, color='k')

        plt.show(block=False)
        plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.show()  # Prevents termination after the loop
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. I maybe wasnt clear, when I run my program I  get the first graph, but then need to close it to go back into the program to run for the second graph.

Comment: So what I am aiming is to have the first graph still visible when I go back into the program to run it to see the second graph.Sorry for me not being clearer

Comment: If I understood correctly, I believe the code does what you want. A graph will remain visible when you plot the next one.